# Using Azure static web app with a Quasar Project

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, azure-static-web-app

I thought it would be pretty simple to host a vuejs quasar project in azure static web apps but I cannot even seem to do the build process from github to publish the website. I can do quasar dev and quasar serve locally and all works great. It is just the assets do not seem to load and trigger a build error for pushing to github/azure. My error comes out as follows:

```
    [vite:asset] Could not load /github/workspace/src/assets/imgs/12.jpg (imported by src/components/HomeRecentWork.vue): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/github/workspace/src/assets/imgs/12.jpg'
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: Could not load /github/workspace/src/assets/imgs/12.jpg (imported by src/components/HomeRecentWork.vue): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/github/workspace/src/assets/imgs/12.jpg'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'PLUGIN_ERROR',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/github/workspace/src/assets/imgs/12.jpg',
  pluginCode: 'ENOENT',
  plugin: 'vite:asset',
  hook: 'load',
  watchFiles: [
    '/github/workspace/index.html',
    '/github/workspace/.quasar/client-entry.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vite/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vue/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@quasar/extras/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@quasar/extras/fontawesome-v6/fontawesome-v6.css',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@quasar/extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass',
    '/github/workspace/.quasar/app.js',
    '/github/workspace/.quasar/quasar-user-options.js',
    '/github/workspace/src/css/app.scss',
    '/github/workspace/src/boot/axios.js',
    'vite/preload-helper',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/vue-plugin.js',
    '/github/workspace/src/App.vue',
    '/github/workspace/src/stores/index.js',
    '/github/workspace/src/router/index.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/plugins/Meta.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/plugins/Notify.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/wrappers/index.mjs',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/index.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/shared/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/shared/dist/shared.esm-bundler.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/install-quasar.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/lang.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/icon-set.js',
    'plugin-vue:export-helper',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/pinia/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vue-router/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs',
    '/github/workspace/src/router/routes.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/plugins/Platform.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/extend.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/components/avatar/QAvatar.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/components/icon/QIcon.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/components/btn/QBtn.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/components/spinner/QSpinner.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/create.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/event.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/global-nodes.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/is.js',
    '\x00commonjsHelpers.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/reactivity/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/plugins/Screen.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/plugins/Dark.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/history.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/body.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/symbols.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/global-config.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/define-reactive-plugin.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/lang/en-US.mjs',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/inject-obj-prop.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/icon-set/material-icons.mjs',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vue-demi/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/devtools-api/package.json',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.mjs',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/@vue/devtools-api/lib/esm/index.js',
    '/github/workspace/src/layouts/MainLayout.vue',
    '/github/workspace/src/pages/IndexPage.vue',
    '/github/workspace/src/pages/ErrorNotFound.vue',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/composables/private/use-size.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/render.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/directives/Ripple.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/components/btn/use-btn.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/private/key-composition.js',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/components/spinner/use-spinner.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js?commonjs-module',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/utils.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/utils.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/mergeConfig.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/mergeConfig.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/Cancel.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/Cancel.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/CancelToken.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/CancelToken.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/isCancel.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/isCancel.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/spread.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/spread.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/isAxiosError.js',
    '\x00/github/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/isAxiosError.js?commonjs-proxy',
    '/github/workspace/node_modules/quasar/src/utils/debounce.js',
    ... 128 more items
  ]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has failed to build the solution.
```

I have not found much info on doing a quasar project inside azure web apps so any advice would be helpful. All the tutorials I have found and gone through do not have these issues and I really do not have a complicated project that deviates from the standard quasar project.

EDIT:
the issue is actually my image paths. I am using  with src="~assets/imgs/embroidery.jpg" where ~ must be an alias setup in quasar. Works for components in quasar but not for raw img tags. If i use a relative path like ../assets/imgs/filename.jpg it still draws an error on build. However, if i do /assets/imgs/filename.jpg and put the assets folder in public it works. I dont want to do this however so how should i put the paths for images in my components if not a vue-component per say?

EDIT
Making my dynamic image links in my scripts as follows fixes the issue but this only works for  tags and not . Not sure why not but this is the code so far:

```
  <div class="row q-pa-md block-wrapper text-center gt-xs" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div v-for="item in imagesArray" :key="item.id" :class="item.size">
      <img :src="item.link"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const imagesArray = [
    { id: 1, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/soccer.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: '' },
    { id: 2, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/groupshirts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: '' },
    { id: 3, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/packaging.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: 'tall' },
    { id: 4, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/eventshirts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: 'wide' },
    { id: 5, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/bacheloretteshirts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: '' },
    { id: 6, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/jerseys.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: 'tall' },
    { id: 7, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/fundraisershirts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: 'big' },
    { id: 8, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/workshirts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: '' },
    { id: 9, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/girlscouts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: 'tall' },
    { id: 10, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/girlsscoccer.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: '' },
    { id: 11, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/companyshirts.jpg', import.meta.url).href, size: '' }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you please share the steps you are trying?

Comment: @Naveen i was able to get it work by using the edit noted above. However, this solution only works if you use <img> tags. I find myself wanting to use <q-img> to take advantage of lazy loading and stuff. Is there any solution to this without having to import everything similar to my fix above.